# Can't convert DataFrame to json using to_json(spreadsheet)

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, converters

I have a xlsx file which is necessary to add to a dict which should be the name of the spreadsheet name... each row of json code is indent=4, axis=4 and convert dates to str format %y%b%d... no name of indexes needed. just simple and clean.

```
import json
import datetime
import pandas as pd

wb = pd.read_excel('/Desktop/test.xlsx')

wb['Date'] = wb['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%y%b%d'))
b = wb.to_json('records')
print(b)
```

Comment: welcome to SO @leleco. Can we get a sample data and what the error code is (or if there aren't any error codes, what the output is and what your expected output is)? just by looking at your code, everything should work fine.